# Automatically Create a .cs file from a class in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I often code in such way that I put several classes in one cs file to get my code going and then at some point, I want to move every class to a seperate .cs file within my C# project but I have to do this manually by creating a file for every class and cut and paste the class to the new file and then resolve the required namespace one by one for each file. No Fun!

Is there a way to just click right on the class and make visual studio to automatically move the class to a new file under the project tree? I mean, would you please provide such Macro/Snippet(or whatever it is called :) ) and instructions on how to add it to Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_Type_to_Another_File_or_Namespace) has the functionality you want (plus so much more).

Comment: I just downloaded Resharper it and tested. It works great but somehow I think my visual studio is slower than before! Hopefully I am wrong!

Comment: @iCode : That is what happens with all the tools, I tried them all, and decided that the constant slowness they cause does not worth having them (even for trial), uninstalled them before the end of trial.

Comment: @iCode... yes.  The tools themselves wind up bloating VS.NET, which is already bloated.  I'm dealing with Re#er now, and hating it, but am forced to use it.

Answer (score 21):

If anyone is looking for a lightweight solution to this problem I found a free Move Type To File extension specifically for this purpose.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5746c6ea-1f92-43f0-8bab-ec6f8573cd6a

Comment: Yeah it's not bad. Seems to have a couple of bugs, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Although I suggested this little utility, I now use Re-sharper myself and I think it's awesome.

Comment: It would be nice if it included the standard using statements that you get when you create a new class normally.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2017 now has Code Refactoring that includes Moving a class into its own file.

- For example you can either right click on the class "Foo" and select "Quick Actions and Refactorings" (or the shortcut Ctrl +)
- Then select "Move type into foo.cs"

Answer (score 1):

1. Ctrl M + M to Collapse the structure you are in (class/interface)
2. Ctrl X , cut the collapsed structure
3. Shift + Alt + C , make new CS (class file, but also you can use it
   for interfaces the same)
4. Type the name of the Class/Interfaces files into the box
5. Copy over the empty  class , page Down , shift up arrow , select the
   class , ctrl V

6.Change the name space if you want ( optional )

This also works with previous and current version (2012) of VS.

Comment: only if this could be automated.

Comment: @e10 : before VS2012, one could record and run macros, but they took that out!

Answer (score 0):

1. C++:
   // Converted from thiscall void CPed::RemoveWeaponAnims(int likeUnused,float blendDelta) 0x5F0250
   void CPed::RemoveWeaponAnims(int likeUnused, float blendDelta)
   {
   ((void (__thiscall *)(CPed*, int, float))0x5F0250)(this, likeUnused, blendDelta);
   }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).